# Testing method which contains Scanner (TestNG)

Tags: java, testng

I'm stuck with testing method that require user input. Here are my methods in IOHandler class:

```
Callable<Integer> getNumber = new Callable<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        try {
            return scanner.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            writeOut("Bad params !\n");
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
        return call();
    }
};

 Optional<Object> handleIOAndGetInput(Callable function) {
    try {
        return Optional.ofNullable(function.call());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Stream doesn't work");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Something went wrong");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

This is method in my Test class:

```
@Test
public void shouldTakeUserInput() {
    IOHandler ioHandler=new IOHandler();
    Assert.assertEquals((ioHandler.handleIOAndGetInput(ioHandler.getNumber)).orElse(null), 5);
}
```

So I red some of similar posts, but I cound't find answear to my problem. Everything I red was about faking input right into assert, but in my case I have to feed this scanner inside Callable getNumber. Looking forward to any tips about it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately this is an instance where you need to stub in the information or use a framework that will stub it in for you

try Mockito

this is a normal issue with java dev.